# Finding a way to display objects efficiently

Tags: xna, c#

I am making a 2D simple Breakout game, and I would like to know of an efficient way to display all the blocks on the screen. I was thinking of dividing the whole screen into little squares that can be occupied by a block or a wall (or most objects). Is this the best way of doing it? Sorry if my question is kinda noob-ish, I just started learning to develop games.

Answer (score 1):

Before all else, you should make sure you need efficiency before you go about trying to implement it.  Although it's possible you (non-)architecture yourself into an irrecoverable situation and have to essentially start over, that's not really a problem.  You will waste more time pondering the best way to implement something than implementing it once, learning some lessons, and re-implementing.  A big refactor is ok.

Onto the direct answer:

For a 2D XNA game, you will get a great deal of efficiency simply by using `Spritebatch` correctly.  It will manage everything involved in minimizing draw calls, etc., so long as you use it as intended.  Create a sprite sheet and draw subsections of it, call `Begin()` only once, don't use the immediate mode, and don't change textures while drawing everything.  If you follow those guidelines (and research if they're unclear), you won't suffer drawing-related performance problems.

If you need to do something more exotic for any purpose, you can generate your complete set of 2D quads and draw them all at once from a single buffer.  That's also fast.

Comment: Alright, I'll try implementing my own way and then maybe improve it a little, even rewriting it maybe. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Don't change textures...at all? That seems a bit impractical for a non-trivial game. Most would have separate sprite sheets per game character, many of which may be required during a render pass. Did you perhaps mean "try to minimize texture usage"?

Comment: @me-- I meant something in the middle of what you've described.  Yes, you can draw from more than one texture.  But if you change textures as few times as possible, then `Spritebatch` can group all those draws into a single set for the GPU, which will be more efficient than sending one draw instruction per quad.  As for your example, you could compile your different characters onto a single texture.  But that optimization would show little benefit (too few characters to matter).  If you were drawing hundreds of similar tiles, you certainly would want to join them into a single texture.